# VSTS Build are getting queued twice on git commit

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm configuring VSTS builds for various projects and setting up continuous integration so they are triggered automatically whenever a commit is made to the bitbucket git repository. For some reason every time I make a commit two builds get queued instead of one.

I tried using the built it bitbucket cloud endpoint and also using an external git and polling it every 60 seconds. I also tried disabling the continuous integrations trigger since I though maybe there was another built in mechanism triggering the builds, but then I got no builds queued.

Comment: How did you trigger VSTS build definition, both selecting CI build and PR request validation? And can you also show screen shots of the two build's summary page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked on the Bitbucket site, how many Webhooks are set up for the repository? It looks like either multiple build definition and/or triggers are/were created for the same repository.

Comment: I see only one webhook. :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to repro this with Bitbucket cloud endpoint (let's focus on getting this work since it offers better integration).  How did you configure your triggers?  Could you please post a screenshot?  Also with the two builds, are they building the same commit?

My config looks like this:
[my Bitbucket build CI trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Rhi.png)

Comment: Here is the configuration for the trigger: [configuration](http://prntscr.com/hwhnyf) .

It is indeed the same commit being built twice.

Comment: Ummm...  That's odd.  Could you please check how the events were pushed from Bitbucket side?  This is my hooks: https://prnt.sc/hxmswo

Specifically, do you see multiple hooks to your visualstudio.com url?  If you only have one, would you please “view details" and see if Bitbucket has sent two requests on that commit VSTS built twice?  

"Batch changes" would also make sure you only have one build running at a time, but that really doesn't tell us why the commit is built twice.

Comment: The first one is pointing to the vsts account: http://prntscr.com/hy6b0e . I'm trying to see the requests but bitbucket is having some problems right now so the request aren't loading.

Comment: Only one request is sent on every commit. But that triggers two builds. 